# How to drop a partition for given day of a week in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Able to drop a partition for a given day of the week i.e Thursday, by hardcoding the value.

ALTER TABLE logs DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(date=2014-10-30);

How to drop a partition for last Thursday(date=2014-10-30) with out hardcoding date value?

Comment: So what date value do you want to drop? You don't know it? If you do, you can hardcode it, if you don't, then the command cannot know either.. What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

One way to dynamically pass date to the hiveql statement is by using hive variables, let assume we have hive script named `alter.hql` and its contents are:

alter.hql

```
ALTER TABLE logs DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (date='${hiveconf:date}');
```

And you can invoke the `alter.hql` by passing the date variable to it:

```
hive -hiveconf date='2014-10-30' -f alter.hql
```